# NextJS 13/14 fetching with Firebase Revalidation

Tags: firebase, next.js, next.js13

I'm building a Food App where I need dynamic routing for a page that displays the different reviews made.

I'm having trouble with `Firebase + NextJS routing`, specifically, finding the equivalent of NextJS Fetching [revalidate:](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) in the Firebase documentation.

**NEXTJS CODE WITHOUT FIREBASE**

With a normal integration, it should look like this:

```
async function getReview(id) {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/reviews/` + id, {
    next: {
      revalidate: 30,
    },
  });

  return res.json();
}
```

**NEXTJS CODE WITH FIREBASE**

```
async function getReview(reviewName) {
  const reviewQ = query(
    collection(db, "reviews"),
    where("name", "==", reviewName)
  );
  const getReviews = await getDocs(reviewQ);

  const res = getReviews.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data() })); // WHERE I SHOULD ADD REVALIDATE??

  return res;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

How can I modify `fetch code block 2` so that Firebase's equivalent of `NextJS Revalidate` occurs when pages are rendered?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why would you need to revalidate data? instead you can use onSnapshot from firebase to get real time data?

Comment: This is not an answer. IT should be a comment instead